# create a nested dictionary from the input given in a text file in python

Tags: python, dictionary, file-io

I have a txt file which contains data in the format:-

```
name1:   #(for student 1)
name2, 1     
name3, 0
name4, 1
…

name2:    #(for student 2)
name1, 0
name3, 0
name4, 0
…
and so on for different students.
```

and the dictionary created should be in the format:-

```
{"name1": {"name2" : 1, "name3" : 0,......}, 
 "name2": {"name1" : 0, "name3" : 0, ......}, 
.....}
```

pls Solve the question without importing any module, simply by file i/o and nested dictionary*
My knowledge of nested dictionaries isn't great, so the furthest I've been able to get is reading the lines into a list, which is not the desired output

```
d = {}
with open (filename) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    for line in content:
        line = line.strip('\r').strip('\n').split(',')
        d[line[0]] = line
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if it's a `name:` line or a `name, number` line.

When it's `name:` start a new nested dictionary with that name, otherwise add to the current nested dictionary.

```
d = {}
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.endswith(':'):
            name = line[:-1]
            d['name'] = {}
        elif line:
            innername, value = line.split(',')
            d['name'][innername] = int(value)
```

I'm assuming the comments like `#(for student 1)` are not part of the file, just description here.

Comment: getting an error  **ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)** in the line **innername, value = line.split(':')** @Barmar

Comment: Sorry, I was supposed to split with `,` not `:`